# How to get original system command after overwriting it with a function?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias, functions

I'm at a Hackathon right now so if someone would answer this soon, you'd be doing me a huge favor.

I've written a function called ls() in my .bashrc that looks like this:

```
ls() {

  if(some condition);
    do something
  else
    ls; #(CALL TO ORIGINAL ls SYSTEM CALL)
  fi

}
```

But here when it goes to the else part, it just enters an infinite loop

How can I call the original ls system call in else
Or, how can I make ls behave differently in one folder and normally in the others.

Comment: did you try to call ls with full path in your else condition?
`/usr/bin/ls`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for `command`:

> command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
>
> Run command with args suppressing the normal shell function lookup. Only builtin commands or commands found in the PATH
>   are executed.  If the -p option is  given,  the
>                     search  for command is performed using a default value for PATH that is guaranteed to find all of the standard
>   utilities.  If either the -V or -v option is supplied, a
>                     description of command is printed.  The -v option causes a single word indicating the command or file name used to
>   invoke command to be displayed; the -V  option  pro‐
>                     duces  a  more verbose description.  If the -V or -v option is supplied, the exit status is 0 if command was found, and 1
>   if not.  If neither option is supplied and an
>                     error occurred or command cannot be found, the exit status is 127.  Otherwise, the exit status of the command builtin is
>   the exit status of command.

Example:

```
$ pwd() {
> echo 'command test'
> command pwd
> }
$ pwd
command test
/etc
```

There is also `builtin`, which is more restrictive:

> builtin shell-builtin [arguments]
>
> Execute  the  specified  shell  builtin,  passing  it arguments, and return its exit status.  This is useful when defining a
>   function whose name is the same as a shell
>                 builtin, retaining the functionality of the builtin within the function.  The cd builtin is commonly redefined this way. 
>   The return status is false  if  shell-builtin
>                 is not a shell builtin command.

Answer (score 1):

You may also be interested in `which`, which gives you the path to the program in your `$PATH` with that name.

```
$ which ping
/bin/ping
```

(Though I'd recommend Nykakin's answer, as it solves your problem. This is just another tool for anyone interested)